# How to run controller action after user clicks button in Jquery dialog, code must loop though all records so user can accept or reject

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am battling with some code in MVC, I managed to pass data form controller to a Jquery dialog widget, now i need to know how to return back to the controller depending on whether the user accepted or rejected the record. There is a list of records I upload as CSV onto MVC View, I then have a button called Validate Claims which calls a stored procedure to validate records, when validate claims is clicked a dialog pops up, with the response from the controller ViewBag passed, I want to then based on the validation response enable user to accept or reject record, when user accepts record it must save it to db then move to the next record. How can I do this in MVC JQuery, please assist.

Please see my code below:

Here is my View Code

```
    @{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}

@*<link href="~/Content/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />*@
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.11.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.11.4.js"></script>
<link href="~/Content/themes/base/dialog.css" rel="stylesheet" />
@*<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui.js"></script>*@

@using CSVSupplierClaims.Models
@model List<CSVSupplierClaims.Models.SupplierClaimsUploadDisplayList>



<input type="submit" id="validateClaims" value="Validate Claims" size="5" />
<input type="submit" value="Import Claims to CRM" size="5" />

<div id="dialog" title="Supplier Claims Validation">
    Claims Upload Confirmation
    <p>
        <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert" style="float:left; margin:0 7px 20px 0;"></span>
        <table id="users" class="ui-widget ui-widget-content" height="100" width="100" border="1">
            <thead>
                <tr class="ui-widget-header ">
                    <th style="width:70%">ST Key</th>
                    <th style="width:70%">Supplier Claim</th>
                    <th style="width:70%">System Cost</th>
                    <th style="width:70%">Orig Inv</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>@ViewBag.ST_Key</td>
                    <td>@ViewBag.SupplierClaim</td>
                    <td>@ViewBag.OrigInv</td>
                    <td>@ViewBag.Error</td>
                    <td>@ViewBag.SystemCost</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </p>
</div>



<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#dialog").dialog({
            autoOpen: false
        });

        $("#validateClaims").click(function () {
            $("#dialog").dialog("open", "resizable");
            $("#dialog").dialog({
                resizable: true,
                height: 300,
                width:500,
                modal: true,
                closeOnEscape: true,
                buttons: {

                    "Accept Claim Record": function (){ 
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                        $(this).empty();
                    },
                    "Reject Claim Record": function () {
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    });

</script>



<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Action</th>
        <th>LineNo</th>
        <th>TotalClaim</th>
        <th>ClaimReference</th>
        <th>Currency</th>
    </tr>
    @if (Model != null)
    {
        foreach (var c in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@c.Action</td>
                <td>@c.LineNo</td>
                <td>@c.TotalClaim</td>
                <td>@c.ClaimReference</td>
                <td>@c.Currency</td>
            </tr>
        }
    }

</table>
@Html.ValidationMessage("Error")

<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <table style="margin-top:150px">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label for="file"> Filename</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="file" name="file" id="file" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Here is my Controller Code

```
using CsvHelper;
using CSVSupplierClaims.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Crm;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;

namespace CSVSupplierClaims.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index(HttpPostedFileBase file)
        {
            string path = null;

            List<SupplierClaimsUploadDisplayList> supplierClaimsData = new List<SupplierClaimsUploadDisplayList>();

            try
            {
                if (file.ContentLength > 0)
                {
                    var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                    path = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "upload\\" + fileName;
                    file.SaveAs(path);

                    var csv = new CsvReader(new StreamReader(path));

                    var supplierList = csv.GetRecords<SupplierClaimsUpload>();



                    foreach (var supplier in supplierList)
                    {
                        SupplierClaimsUploadDisplayList supplierUploadDisplay = new SupplierClaimsUploadDisplayList();

                        supplierUploadDisplay.Action = supplier.Action;
                        supplierUploadDisplay.LineNo = supplier.LineNo;
                        supplierUploadDisplay.TotalClaim = supplier.TotalClaim;
                        supplierUploadDisplay.ClaimReference = supplier.ClaimReference;
                        supplierUploadDisplay.Currency = supplier.Currency;

                        supplierClaimsData.Add(supplierUploadDisplay);
                    }

                }
            }
            catch
            {
                ViewData["error"] = "Uplaod failed";
            }
            Supplier_Claim_Upload_Result supplierClaimUplaod = new Supplier_Claim_Upload_Result();

            var sqlConnection = "data source=WMVSQL02;initial catalog=Embrace;integrated security=True;";

            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(sqlConnection))
            {
                try
                {
                    foreach (var claim in supplierClaimsData)
                    {
                        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
                        cmd.CommandTimeout = 60;
                        SqlDataReader reader;
                        cmd.CommandText = "CRM.Supplier_Claim_Upload";
                        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Invoice", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = claim.LineNo;
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Amount", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = claim.TotalClaim;
                        cmd.Connection = conn;

                        conn.Open();
                        reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                        while (reader.Read())
                        {
                            supplierClaimUplaod.ST_Key = reader["ST_Key"].ToString();
                            if (supplierClaimUplaod.SupplierClaim != null)
                            {
                                supplierClaimUplaod.SupplierClaim = reader["Supplier_Claim"].ToString();
                            }
                            else if (supplierClaimUplaod.SupplierClaim == null && supplierClaimUplaod.OrigInv == null && supplierClaimUplaod.SystemCost == null)
                            {
                                if (supplierClaimUplaod.Error != null)
                                {
                                    supplierClaimUplaod.Error = reader["Error"].ToString();
                                }
                                else if (supplierClaimUplaod.Error == null)
                                {
                                    supplierClaimUplaod.SupplierClaim = "No value";
                                }
                            }
                            if (supplierClaimUplaod.OrigInv != null)
                            {
                                supplierClaimUplaod.OrigInv = reader["Orig_Inv"].ToString();
                            }
                            else if (supplierClaimUplaod.OrigInv == null)
                            {
                                if (supplierClaimUplaod.Error != null)
                                {
                                    supplierClaimUplaod.Error = reader["Error"].ToString();
                                }
                                else if (supplierClaimUplaod.Error == null)
                                {
                                    supplierClaimUplaod.OrigInv = "No value";
                                }
                            }
                            if (supplierClaimUplaod.SystemCost != null)
                            {
                                supplierClaimUplaod.SystemCost = reader["System_Cost"].ToString();
                            }
                            else if (supplierClaimUplaod.SystemCost == null)
                            {
                                if (supplierClaimUplaod.Error != null)
                                {
                                    supplierClaimUplaod.Error = reader["Error"].ToString();
                                }
                                else if (supplierClaimUplaod.Error == null)
                                {
                                    supplierClaimUplaod.SystemCost = "No Value";
                                }
                            }
                        }


                        if (supplierClaimUplaod != null)
                        {
                            ViewBag.ST_Key = supplierClaimUplaod.ST_Key;
                            ViewBag.SupplierClaim = supplierClaimUplaod.SupplierClaim;
                            ViewBag.OrigInv = supplierClaimUplaod.OrigInv;
                            ViewBag.Error = supplierClaimUplaod.Error;
                            ViewBag.SystemCost = supplierClaimUplaod.SystemCost;

                            ViewBag.Confirmation = supplierClaimUplaod.Error +
                                                   supplierClaimUplaod.OrigInv +
                                                   supplierClaimUplaod.ST_Key +
                                                   supplierClaimUplaod.SupplierClaim +
                                                   supplierClaimUplaod.SystemCost;

                            return View(supplierClaimsData);
                        }

                        conn.Close();

                    }

                }
                catch (Exception)
                {

                    throw;
                }
            }



            return View(supplierClaimsData);
        }

    }
}
```

I managed to pass the controller response to the dialog, I am struggling trigger the loop to go back to the controller and got through all the records. When a user click on Accept Record I want to go back to the controller, and maybe save the record somewhere(sql) and validate the next record and so on, I am basically asking how can I wire up the Jquery button click Accept or Reject to go back to the controller and run additional code based on what button the user selected.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with an ajax call to your controller action.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "@Url.Action("YourAction", "YourController")",
    data: some_parameters
    type: "POST",
    success: function(response){ },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { }
});
```

[Here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) for more details